# Confidence Interval for Sample Mean in Python (Different from Manual)

Tags: python, data-science

I'm trying to create some material for introductory statistics for a seminar. The above code computes a 95% confidence interval for estimating the mean, but the result is not the same from the one implemented in Python. Is there something wrong with my math / code? Thanks.

EDIT:

Data was sampled from here

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(60000,15000,200)
income = pd.DataFrame()
income = pd.DataFrame()
income['Data Scientist'] = x

# Manual Implementation
sample_mean = income['Data Scientist'].mean()
sample_std = income['Data Scientist'].std()
standard_error = sample_std / (np.sqrt(income.shape[0]))
print('Mean',sample_mean)
print('Std',sample_std)
print('Standard Error',standard_error)
print('(',sample_mean-2*standard_error,',',sample_mean+2*standard_error,')')


# Python Library
import scipy.stats as st
se = st.sem(income['Data Scientist'])
a = st.t.interval(0.95, len(income['Data Scientist'])-1, loc=sample_mean, scale=se)
print(a)
print('Standard Error from this code block',se)
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data to reproduce.

Comment: Sorry. Data is only synthetic data. It was sampled from here. x = np.random.normal(60000,15000,200)

Comment: Please include your actual code, not a screenshot. We cannot execute code from a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited thanks.

Comment: The difference is almost 20-30. It's not a matter of real numbers less than 1.

Comment: I don't have an issue between the difference in the Standard Error. I have a problem with the lower and upper bounds of the interval.

Comment: The confidence interval is built by the point estimate + or - 2xSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 2 errors.

First, you are using 2 for the multiplier for the CI.  The more accurate value is 1.96.  "2" is just a convenient estimator.  That is making your CI generated manually too fat.

Second, you are comparing a normal distribution to the t-distribution.  This probably isn't causing more than decimal dust in difference because you have 199 degrees of freedom for the t-dist, which is basically the normal.

Below is the z-score of 1.96 and computation of CI with apples-to-apples comparison to the norm distribution vs. t.

```
In [45]: st.norm.cdf(1.96)                                                                   
Out[45]: 0.9750021048517795

In [46]: print('(',sample_mean-1.96*standard_error,',',sample_mean+1.96*standard_error,')')  
( 57558.007862202685 , 61510.37559873406 )

In [47]: st.norm.interval(0.95, loc=sample_mean, scale=se)                                   
Out[47]: (57558.044175045005, 61510.33928589174)
```